# How to check if GameObject have EventTrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I think to use:

```
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit)){
        if(hit.transform.GetComponent<EventTrigger>()){
            //do something
        }
```

but i cant.

Comment: "Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't." - Check for null.

Comment: Your code is correct. Put the code to run inside that `if` statement.

Comment: Yeah it works i just forgot to add in script: using UnityEngine.EventSystems;